# Using kohannenkappa loss function in keras models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, tensor

Trying to use non keras backend functions for custom loss calculation in keras models.

I am trying to make my keras cnn model use a custom loss function ( KAppa score). However since kappas is not defined in Keras backend , i need to used scikit-learn based kappa implementation. This sklearn function takes array of labels as the argument unlike keras backend functions which take tensors. The loss function call within keras mostly sends tensors Y_pred and Y_true. I did the implementation below using some quide i found online but I get errors .

```
import keras.backend as K
def cohen_kappa_score_func(y_true, y_pred):
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        score  = cohen_kappa_score(type(y_true.eval()),type(y_pred.eval()), weights='linear')#idea is to convert the tensor to array
        sess.close()
    return score
#use this later to compile the keras model with custom loss function as 
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9),
                    loss=cohen_kappa_score_func,
                    metrics=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mae','categorical_accuracy'])
```

This doesnt work and i get the following error

"InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_15_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[node dense_15_target "

Please give me suggestios to solve this.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?